# Interactive europe map with values in each country

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, plotly

I would like to create an interactive map of Europe with `plotly()` or `ggplot()`. All countries should be filled with a light gray by default. For certain countries there are mean values that are previously saved in individual variables. These mean values per country should be placed and displayed in the middle of the respective country (in black). Depending on the mean value, the countries (which have a mean value) should be colored in shades of green - higher prices in darker green and lower prices in lighter green.

I get always the mean values of following countries (value is variable):

```
meanGermany <- 33.33
meanAustria <- 35.71
meanNetherlands <- 35.9
meanBelgium <- 34.66
meanFrance <- 34.89
meanItaly <- 43.97
meanHungary <- 43.96
meanCroatia <- 42.54
meanBulgaria <- 54.61
meanGreece <- 25.72
meanNorway <- 27.64
meanSweden <- 36.41
meanFinland <- 32.13
meanDenmark <- 36.83
meanSlovakia <- 35.94
meanCzechia <- 44.15
meanRomania <- 36.52
meanSwitzerland <- 44.12
meanSerbia <- 45.53
meanSlovenia <- 45.1
```

The europe map should look like this by default:

[image]

The color palette should be something like this:

`scale_color_manual(values = colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(n = 8, name = "Greens")[5:8])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code

```
#Load required packages
library(rnaturalearth)
library(plotly) 
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)
library(RColorBrewer)

# Get the world map
world <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")
class(world)
plot(world)
head(world)

# Select only the states member of the E.U.
europe <- world[world$region_un=="Europe"&world$name!="Russia",]

#See the head of the data
head(europe)

#Plot the europe map
ggplot(europe) +
  geom_sf(color="black",
          size=.1, show.legend = T) +
  theme_bw()

#Read the data
df <- read.table(header = T, text = "Country, Mean
Germany, 33.33
Austria, 35.71
Netherlands, 35.9
Belgium, 34.66
France, 34.89
Italy, 43.97
Hungary, 43.96
Croatia, 42.54
Bulgaria, 54.61
Greece, 25.72
Norway, 27.64
Sweden, 36.41
Finland, 32.13
Denmark, 36.83
Slovakia, 35.94
Czechia, 44.15
Romania, 36.52
Switzerland, 44.12
Serbia, 45.53
Slovenia, 45.1", sep=",")

#Selecting specific countries using `dplyr` package
europe <- world %>% 
  dplyr::filter(region_un=="Europe" & name %in% df$Country) 

#Plot the selected countries
ggplot(europe) +
  geom_sf(color="black",
  size=.1, show.legend = T)
```

[image]

```
#Add the data to the shapefile
europe_df <- europe %>% left_join(df, by=c("name_long" ="Country"))

#Get the centroid of each state polygon as the coordinates where to display the mean values
europe_df <- cbind(europe_df, st_coordinates(st_centroid(europe_df)))

#Plotting using ggplot2
p <- ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data=europe_df,aes(fill=Mean), inherit.aes=F, alpha=0.9) +
  geom_point(data=europe_df,
             aes(x=X, y=Y)) +
  labs(x="Longitude", y="Latitude") +
  scale_fill_distiller(name = "Mean", palette = "Greens") +
  theme_bw()

#Convert it into plotly
ggplotly(p)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The map of Europe can look like the one in my picture above. Your map is zoomed in way too far.  I would also like the countries to be completely filled in with colors and not just a colored point in the country. The mean of e.g. Germany should be displayed in country Germany as 33.33 and then this country should be filled with a lighter green. Bulgaria has a mean of 54.61 (this should be written in the middle of Bulgaria) und the whole country should be filled with a dark green

Comment: You just replace the shapefile with yours. I have updated my answer to colour the country according to mean values. If you can provide the shapefile you are using, I can update my answer.

Comment: Ok thank you for the information. I have already plotted the europe map on my own with the coloring. But I have some other questions, should I edit my question or ask a new one?

Comment: Better to ask a new question.